# undefined $link? "mysqli_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be.."

Tags: php, mysql

$link has been previously defined, yet the code throws said error on

- **if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){**

and

- **mysqli_close($link);**

It might as well be biting me in the knee, but I fail to see the issue...

```
function connect(){
   //connection to DB
   $link = mysqli_connect($this->database_socket, $this->db_username, $this->db_password, $this->db_name);
   if(mysqli_connect_error()){ 
       die(mysqli_connect_error());
   }else{
     return $link;
   }
}


// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
...
    
    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
            
...
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

Comment: Is all of this inside the same file? Where do you call your `connect` function?

Comment: Where do you call `connect()`? Please show us the full code